# How to change columns attributes in phpspreadsheet html reader

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

in my php file I'm exporting some data from html node to an excel file.

```
<?php 
$data = $_POST['data']; //data is the html string
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Html();
$spreadsheet = $reader->loadFromString($data);
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('../exportado' . date("Y-m-d") . '.xlsx');
?>
```

However, I need to change the columns attributes to make it easy to read, considering the long data that's exporting.

Seeing the PHPSpreadSheet docs, I've been found in the Xlsx reader the "setColumnAttributes" method, which can change that.

> setColumnAttributes()
> Set Worksheet column attributes by attributes array passed.

There's a way to do it with HTML Reader?

Comment: So the problem is that some values is too long and the text does not fit in a cell?

Comment: No, the problem is the columns attributes (indexes names)